# How to convert linked columns of a table to rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I have a table as follows:

```
ID | Fileid1 | Fileid2 | Fileid3 | LanguageID1 | LanguageID2 | LanguageID3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 123     | 256     |         | a12         | a23         | 
2  | 124     |         |         | a12         |             |
```

Here the `LanguageID1` corresponds to `Fileid1`, `LanguageID2` corresponds to `Fileid2` and so on.

I want to convert this into the following:

```
ID | Field | LangaugeID
1  | 123   | a12
2  | 256   | a23
3  | 124   | a12
```

I have tried using `UNPIVOT` on both these fields but it gives a relation between all the columns. What should be the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union:

```
select row_number() over(order by ID, Fileid) as ID,
Fileid,
LanguageID 
from
(select ID, Fileid1 as Fileid, LanguageID1 as LanguageID from table_name
union all select ID, Fileid2 as Fileid, LanguageID2 as LanguageID from table_name
union all select ID, Fileid3 as Fileid, LanguageID3 as LanguageID from table_name) t
where Fileid is not null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1688abac8d8f4c84dd5fe0bc563a7c7b)

Comment: What is Fileid is null and LanguageID  is not null ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76bddfc3baf3c780dfef093d760e75b9

Comment: Since the the languageID corresponds to FieldID, this case is not possible as per my database

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select id, Fileid, LanguageID
from (
        select id,fileid1 as Fileid,LanguageID1 as LanguageID 
        from  my_table 
      union all 
        select id,fileid2 as Fileid ,LanguageID2 as LanguageID
        from  my_table 
      union all 
       select id,fileid3 as Fileid ,LanguageID3 as LanguageID
       from  my_table 
       ) as t1
where concat_ws('',Fileid,LanguageID) !=''
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=267beb592990979f3f4ffb939332c4f6)